# How to force Chrome disk cache size and directory location?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, windows-registry

There is a [command-line switch for Chrome](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) for setting Disk cache size and location.
Mine looks like this: `--disk-cache-dir="C:\0\cache" --disk-cache-size=1073741824`

If you want to have these settings **all-the-time**, you need to modify *ALL* your icons, and your registry.

I have modified all my icons. And my registry.
However, **my registry reverts all the time**. How can I protect my registry from this?

The registry modification looks like this (exported it from my registry; .reg file):

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
>   @="\"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\"
>   --disk-cache-dir=\"C:\0\cache\" --disk-cache-size=1073741824 --
>   \"%1\""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not change HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR). This is simply a merged view from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.

- If you wish to make a change that **affects all users** that can connect to the machine, use:

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`
- If you wish to make changes that **affect only the current user**, use:

  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`

---

**Note:** Depending on how Chrome was installed, you may not see one of these; i.e. if it was installed just for the current user, "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML" will be missing). But You can move and copy from one key to the other if you want.

**For more information**: See [Windows registry Information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256986)

Comment: Well, it's got the same value in the LOCAL_MACHINE, but the change gets reverted for some reason ... somehow ... I don't know. :/

Comment: @Shiki Another issue I'm noting is the lack of double backslashes inside the paths

Comment: Nevermind that last comment. It's an export

Comment: @Shiki. Being that the case, here comes my stupid question. Have you rebooted after changing the value?

Comment: No point in rebooting. Not at all. Computers are not magic, and "reboot" is no magic spell.